# Passing Windows Token to WCF then from WCF to another server in the AD domain

Tags: .net, wcf, security

This may be a doozy, but does anyone have an idea how to:

Pass the users windows token (authenticated from domain) to the wcf service that is called - the service would then perform an action based on the users windows credentials that made the call.

ie: Client -> WCF -> SOME 3rd PARTY REPOSITORY THAT INTEGRATES WITH ACTIVE DIRECTORY.

I have a wcf data tier that is responsible for returning all of the data - currently the customer makes calls to this service.  This service retrieves documents from a repository.  The customer would like to accomplish this by managing all of the accounts with AD sincee the repository supports AD integration.

Any help would be appreciated - thank you :-)

---------- update
I have followed jezell's article but i still have issues.

I want to use upn as opposed to spn (so that the account can be locked down and more secure), but im not sure what i've got that is wrong.

I have created the spn's on the AD server (tried every combination, no duplicates)

Here is some code snippet, maybe someone has an idea of what im doing wrong.

```
Dim binding As New NetTcpBinding()
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message
binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows

Dim upn As String = "usertest@testdomain.com"

Dim ep As New EndpointAddress(New Uri("net.tcp://server1.testdomain.com:1111/ServiceTest") _
    , EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity(upn))

Dim factory As New ChannelFactory(Of Credential.Interface.ICredentialTest)(binding, ep)
factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = False
factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation

Dim iproxy As Credential.Interface.ICredentialTest = factory.CreateChannel()
Dim co As ICommunicationObject = CType(iproxy, ICommunicationObject)
iproxy.ToService(result)
```

---

Now i get the error: 'The identity check failed for outgoing message.   The expected identity is...
All i can find on this relates to using certificates, which im not doing.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as delegation. Set the allowed impersonation level in the client configuration to "Delegation" and disable NTLM authentication on the server side. I have a post with a more in depth discussion here:

http://www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Delegation+-+WCF+Gotcha+2.aspx